# Auto change the sample border when visitor key-in color code in an input textfield

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to auto change sample border when visitor key-in color code in input textfield at:

Do you have a particular border colour you would like?

```
input name="ContentInclude:borderspecs" type="text" maxlength="200" id="ContentInclude_borderspecs" tabindex="5" style="width:500px"
```

https://advertiser.seek.com.au/advertisers/catalogue/templaterequest.ascx

The sample code start with: begin sample template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
<input name="ContentInclude:borderspecs" type="text" maxlength="200" 
    id="ContentInclude_borderspecs" tabindex="5" style="width:500px" 
    onkeyup="javascript:changeBorderColor(this);">
```

JS code:

```
<script>
function changeBorderColor(elem){
    var template = document.getElementById('sampletemplate');
    if (elem.value.match(/^\#([\dabcdef]{3}|[\dabcdef]{6})$/i)) { // HEX code
        template.style.borderColor = elem.value;
    }
    // more else if to match other possible values
    else { // reset to default
        template.style.borderColor = null; // or "black"
    }
}
</script>
```

// edited so it changes the color of template preview `div#sampletemplate`

Comment: The sample border which should change is 'Your Sample ad template' and border surrounding JOB TITLE and some text like 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris dui magna, ullamcorper et,...'

Comment: is that the div#sampletemplate?